# Select Count from One to Many Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, one-to-many

I am using MS SQL.

I have a access group/permission one to many table setup for my security system. Users are assigned a Group. Each group can have a number of various permissions. I need a select statement that checks (returns a count) if a group has a specific permission.

The data I will have for the select statement is the GroupID of the User and the permissionName they are requesting access to.

Logically what I need is:

1. Get the ID of the permissionName. `pID = SELECT permissionID FROM Permission_List WHERE permissionName = 'News'`
2. Check `Group_Permission` Table to see if `GroupID` of the User intersects with permissionID equaling pID
3. If the count is 0 the group doesn't have access. If the count is 1 the group has access.(I'll handle this in PHP)

#### TABLE: Group_List

```
groupID     groupName       groupDesc
1           Standard        Normal Access Level.
2           Limited         Limited Access Level.
3           Medium          Medium Access Level.
```

#### TABLE: Permission_List

```
permissionID    permissionName  permissionProtect   permissionDesc
1               News            0                   News section access.
2               Forums          0                   Forums section access.
3               Contacts        0                   Contact section access.
```

#### TABLE: Group_Permission

```
groupID     permissionID
1           1
1           2
1           3
2           1
3           1
3           2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to `JOIN` the tables together and use the `COUNT` aggregate.  For this example, I've assumed you are supplying a group id and a permission name.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Group_Permission GP
    JOIN Permission_List PL ON GP.permissionId = PL.permissionId
WHERE PL.permissionName = 'News'
    AND GP.groupId = @someGroupId
```

If count is greater than 0, then the permission exists for that group.